# Differences Between Row Echelon and Reduced Row Echelon

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $$A =\begin{bmatrix} 1&3&-6&2\\5&12&-24&7\\9&15&-30&6\end{bmatrix}$$

$$RREF(A) =\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0&-1\\0&1&-2&-1\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$
$$REF(A) =\begin{bmatrix} 1&3&-6&2\\0&1&-2&1\\0&0&0&0\\\end{bmatrix}$$

Now, provided this information, it can be found that the basis for the nullspace of $A$ using the $RREF(A)$ is: $$\begin{pmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0\\2\\1\\0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 1\\-1\\0\\1 \end{bmatrix}\end{pmatrix}$$

Using the $REF(A)$ the "basis" for the nullspace is:

$$\begin{pmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 6\\2\\1\\0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} -2\\-1\\0\\1 \end{bmatrix}\end{pmatrix}$$

Is the "basis" that I provided for the $REF(A)$ actually a basis? How does the  $REF$ and $RREF$ of a matrix differ?

Comment: Difference between REF and RREF:
**REF**: 1. Each nonzero row lies above every zero row.
2. The leading entry of a nonzero row lies in a column to the right of the column with the leading entry of any preceding row. 3. If a column contains the leading entry of some row, then all entries of that column below the leading entry are 0.
**RREF**:
the same conditions but also
4. If a column contains the leading entry of some row, then all the other entries of that column are 0.
5. The leading entry of each nonzero row is 1.
[Source:](http://math.illinoisstate.edu/hjordon/Math175/9-1.pdf)

Comment: Additional note that RREF takes longer but the values can be read straight off, whereas REF requires back substitution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main difference is that it is easy to read the null space off the RREF, but it takes more work for the REF.

Applying a row operation to $A$ amounts to left-multiplying $A$ by an elementary matrix $E$. This preserves the null space, as $Av = 0 \iff EA v = 0$ (elementary matrices are invertible). Hence both $A$ and its RREF (and REF) have the same null space, and it is a simple matter to read off the null space from the RREF.

Answer (score 2):

From Williams ([source](http://samples.jbpub.com/9780763782498/82498_ch08_sec01_williams.pdf)), pg. 348:

> The difference between a reduced echelon form and an echelon form is that the elements above and below a leading 1 are zero in a reduced echelon form, while only the elements below the leading 1 need be zero in an echelon form.

Examples and further discussion are given in the above text.

Another great resource is available [here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-Echelon-and-reduced-echelon-form).

Answer (score 0):

Row Echelon form(REF) requires backward  substitution while
Row Reduce Echelon form (RREF) requires no backward substitution.